# rtmpt protocol dump handshake error

Tags: rtmp, live-streaming

When I try to dump rtmpt protocol with rtmpdump in Ubuntu, I got this error:

```
ERROR: RTMP_Connect1, handshake failed.
```

I would like to dump:

```
rtmpdump -v -r  "rtmpt://37.130.228.52:80/atv/atv3"
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. First of all the ip addresses for rtmp url was changing between few ip addresses.When I try the other ip numbers it was connecting to the rtmp but it was being rejected instantly. This was due swf verification, that is some rtmp urls also needs swf verification. Hence, when I typed as follow it successfully play on vlc player.

```
rtmpdump -v -r  "rtmpt://..../atv/atv3" -s http://....swf?i=1 | vlc -
```

Next problem is that I want to play this rtmp with avconv/avplay not with vlc player. I could not give swfurl parameter succesfully in avplay. Instead this we can also dump with rtmpdump first and pipe it with avplay or avconv but I could not achieve this as well.

Edit: Second problem is solved with

> rtmpdump ...... | avplay -i pipe:0